# Writing a trigonometric function in terms of another for theta in a given quadrant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\tan ^{  }{ \theta  }$ in terms of $\cos ^{  }{ \theta  } $ in quadrant III

I suppose that using the second pythagorean identity: $\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } +1=\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } $

I have a general idea of how to manipulate this equation... but I am stuck in terms of arriving at the correct answer. This is as far as I have gotten:

$$\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } =\sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } -1$$
$$\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } =\frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  } -1$$
$$\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } =\frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  } -(\sin ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } +\cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } )$$

I feel very lost going from here. I probably didn't even head in the right direction to begin with. I would prefer a hint to set me on the right path rather than a direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $$\tan^2\theta=\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$$

Now in the $III$ Quadrant $\tan\theta\ge0$

So, $$\tan\theta=+\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}$$

Comment: Why is the answer negative and yours is positive?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, The answer may not be right always, as http://www.math-only-math.com/all-sin-tan-cos-rule.html